# Is Linux kernel parameters separated by space (0x20) or NUL (0x0)?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

I thought it was NUL. But today when I wrote a script, I found that it was space. Is it configurable? Or just my memory wrong?

Comment: Configurable? I don't think so. They're a chunk of memory, kernel read and get info from it(using space character as separator), userspace can also read it by `/proc/cmdline`

Comment: @神秘德里克 Thanks. Wondering why I had the NUL memory.

Comment: Might because your boot loader transfer a NUL. I believe the interface is always a continous chunk of memory, no matter write by bootloader or read by /proc/cmdline. Although kernel might use different internal structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this has led to a mix-up in your memory:

In `/proc/cmdline` (i.e., command-line arguments for the kernel itself), arguments are separated by 0x20.

In `/proc/`*some_process_id*`/cmdline` (i.e., command-line arguments for individual user processes), arguments are separated by 0x00.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about how they appear in `/proc/cmdline`, they're separated by spaces. It's not configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the parse function here:
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18.13/source/lib/cmdline.c#L199

```
/*
* Parse a string to get a param value pair.
* You can use " around spaces, but can't escape ".
* Hyphens and underscores equivalent in parameter names.
*/
```